# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ', ' to data type int in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Error occurs in these lines:

```
Select
    @RankId = @RankId + ', ' + ID 
From
    RANKS 
Where
    RANKS.ID IN (Select RANK_ID 
                 From WORKFLOW_RANK 
                 Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

Select 
    @LocationId = @LocationId + ', ' + ID 
From 
    LOCATIONS 
Where 
    LOCATIONS.ID in (Select LOCATION_ID 
                     From WORKFLOW_LOCATION 
                     Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)
```

`RankId` and `LocationId` are declared as `int` in tables.

Complete code is:

```
Declare @i As Int
    ,@mx    As Int
    ,@Ranks As nVarchar(250)
    ,@Loc   As nVarchar(250)
    ,@WF    As nVarchar(250)
    ,@WFID as int
    ,@RankId as int
    ,@LocationId as int

Create Table #Result (ID Int Identity(1,1),WORKFLOW_ID  int,WORKFLOW nVarchar(100), RANKS Varchar(250), LOCATIONS Varchar(250),RankId int,LocationId int)

Insert Into #Result (WORKFLOW_ID, WORKFLOW) 
    Select Distinct ID, WORKFLOW_NAME 
    From [WORKFLOW] 
    Where ID = 1

Select @i = 1, @mx = Max(ID) 
From #Result

While (@i < = @Mx)
Begin
    Select 
        @WFID = WORKFLOW_ID, 
        @WF = WorkFlow, 
        @Ranks = '',
        @Loc = ''  
    From 
        #Result 
    Where 
        ID = @i

    Select 
        @Ranks = @Ranks + ', ' + RANK_NAME 
    From 
        RANKS 
    Where 
        RANKS.ID in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK 
                     Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

    Select 
        @Loc = @Loc + ', ' + LOCATION_NAME 
    From 
        LOCATIONS 
    Where 
        LOCATIONS.ID in (Select LOCATION_ID From WORKFLOW_LOCATION 
                         Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

    Select 
        @RankId = @RankId + ', ' + ID 
    From 
        RANKS 
    Where 
        RANKS.ID in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK 
                     Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

    Select 
        @LocationId = @LocationId + ', ' + ID 
    From 
        LOCATIONS 
    Where 
        LOCATIONS.ID in (Select LOCATION_ID From WORKFLOW_LOCATION 
                         Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

    Update #Result 
    Set RANKS = Right(@Ranks, Len(@Ranks) - 2), 
        LOCATIONS = Right(@Loc, Len(@Loc) - 2),
        RankId = Right(@RankId, Len(@RankId) - 2),
        LocationId = Right(@LocationId, Len(@LocationId) - 2)
    Where ID = @i

    SET @i = @i + 1
End

Select * From #Result
Drop Table #Result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL,You can't combine or add a string character to an integer value explicitly. Use `CAST` or `CONVERT` function to achieve this.

Try with the below query. Since you are storing as string change the datatype of the variables `@RankId` and `@LocationId`

```
DECLARE @RankId VARCHAR(8000)
DECLARE @LocationId  VARCHAR(8000)
```

1st query :

```
  Select @RankId = COALESCE(@RankId + ',', '') + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(50)) 
  From RANKS 
  Where RANKS.ID in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)
```

2 nd one :

```
  Select @LocationId = COALESCE(@LocationId + ',', '') +  CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(50)) 
  From LOCATIONS 
  Where LOCATIONS.ID in (Select LOCATION_ID From WORKFLOW_LOCATION Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)
```

**full code should change like below :**

```
Declare @i As Int
    ,@mx    As Int
    ,@Ranks As nVarchar(250)
    ,@Loc   As nVarchar(250)
    ,@WF    As nVarchar(250)
    ,@WFID as int
    ,@RankId as Varchar(250)
    ,@LocationId as Varchar(250)

Create Table #Result (ID Int Identity(1,1),WORKFLOW_ID  int,WORKFLOW nVarchar(100), RANKS Varchar(250), LOCATIONS Varchar(250),RankId VARCHAR(250),LocationId VARCHAR(250))

Insert Into #Result (WORKFLOW_ID,WORKFLOW) Select Distinct ID,WORKFLOW_NAME From [WORKFLOW] where ID=1

Select @i = 1, @mx = Max(ID) From #Result

WHILE (@i < = @Mx)
    Begin
        Select @WFID=WORKFLOW_ID, @WF = WorkFlow, @Ranks = '',@Loc =''  From #Result Where ID = @i

        Select @Ranks = @Ranks + ', ' + RANK_NAME From RANKS Where RANKS.ID in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

        Select @Loc = @Loc + ', ' + LOCATION_NAME From LOCATIONS Where LOCATIONS.ID in (Select LOCATION_ID From WORKFLOW_LOCATION Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

       Select @RankId = COALESCE(@RankId + ',', '') + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(50)) 
       From RANKS 
       Where RANKS.ID in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

       Select @LocationId = COALESCE(@LocationId + ',', '') +  CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(50)) 
       From LOCATIONS 
       Where LOCATIONS.ID in (Select LOCATION_ID From WORKFLOW_LOCATION Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

        Update #Result Set RANKS =Right(@Ranks,Len(@Ranks)-2), 

        LOCATIONS = Right(@Loc,Len(@Loc)-2),

        RankId = Right(@RankId,Len(@RankId)-2),

        LocationId = Right(@LocationId,Len(@LocationId)-2)

        Where ID = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    End

Select * From #Result
Drop Table #Result
```

Comment: I tried with the above query but it shows null in RankId and LocationId field.

Comment: For using updated query the error is "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2,3' to data type int."  and error comes at line "Update #Result Set RANKS =Right(@Ranks,Len(@Ranks)-2), "

Comment: Since you are storing values as comma separated,make rankID and LocationId of the columns as string. See the updated script.

Comment: The id of Ranks Master, Chief Officer and HR are 1,2 and 3 and Id of locations anre 1,2 and 3. But when I apply yours latest updated query it shows 2,3 in both RankId and LocationId fields of Result table.

Comment: Its working when I change the length of right function.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error since you are trying to append a `varchar` and `int` datatype. If you are using **SQL Server 2008 or lower version** you have to convert everything into varchar and then append it.

```
DECLARE @RankId VARCHAR(1000)

Select @RankId = COVERT(VARCHAR(50),@RankId) + ', ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),ID) 
From RANKS Where RANKS.ID 
in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)
```

And if you are using **SQL Server 2012 or higher**, then you have a function [CONCAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

```
DECLARE @RankId VARCHAR(1000)

Select @RankId = CONCAT(@RankId,',',ID) 
From RANKS Where RANKS.ID 
in (Select RANK_ID From WORKFLOW_RANK Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)

DECLARE @LocationId VARCHAR(1000)

Select @LocationId = CONCAT(@LocationId, ', ', ID)
From LOCATIONS Where LOCATIONS.ID 
in (Select LOCATION_ID From WORKFLOW_LOCATION Where WORKFLOW_ID = @WFID)
```

**Update**: You need to declare `@RankId` and @LocationId  as `varchar(1000)`

Comment: I tried with the above query but it shows null in RankId and LocationId field.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2012, and I use the second Query,it shows the error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ',1' to data type int."

Comment: @Kedarnath What's the datatype of `WORKFLOW_ID` and `@WFID`??

Comment: Both are integers.

Comment: @Kedarnath Which value is one?

Comment: I dont know correctly.Actually Workflow Id,Rank Id and Location Id is from 3 different tables and all have the value 1. Also here I use where condition with check ID=1 in first insert condition.

Comment: @Kedarnath Updated my the answer. Check now.

Comment: @Kedarnath You have the datatypes of `RankId` and `LocationId` to varchar(1000) in the store procedure and then use the `CONACT` function.

Comment: Select @LocationId = CONCAT(LocationId + ', ' + ID) or Select LocationId = CONCAT(LocationId, ', ' ,ID) which is correct? First one have syntax error.

Comment: For using second query the error is "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2,3' to data type int." and error comes at line "Update #Result Set RANKS =Right(@Ranks,Len(@Ranks)-2),

Comment: @Kedarnath Make it as `Update #Result Set RANKS =CONVERT(INT,Right(@Ranks,Len(@Ranks)-2))`

Comment: shows the error "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Master, Chief Officer, HR' to data type int." on the last updated line(Update #Result Set RANKS =CONVERT(INT,Right(@Ranks,Len(@Ranks)-2)),)

Comment: Hi I got the solution,Thank you very much Jibin for yours support.